# Trouble with Django ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, forms

Hi bit of a beginner question about using django's modelchoicefield in a form I'm building.

I just need  get django to display a drop down list of ingredients in a form. I've gotten to the point where the page renders but the form does not, I was getting errors before so I am kind of perplexed at the moment. I was hoping for some guidance.

Using python 2.7.6 and django 1.6.2. If I left anything out let me know.

Thanks!

Code is below:

views:

```
    args = {}
#add csrf sercurity
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = form
return render_to_response('newMeal.html', args)
```

form:

from django import forms
from models import meals, ingredients, recipe

class mealForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
breakfast = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=recipe.objects.all())
# Lunch = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=recipe.objects.all())
# Dinner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=recipe.objects.all())


class Meta:
    model = meals
    fields = ('Breakfast','Lunch','Dinner','servingDate')
```

class recipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = recipe
    fields = ('Name', 'Directions')
```

template:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>New Meals go here!</p>

<form action="/meals/newmeal/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="selection">
        {{form.as_table}}


        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Meal"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Model;

from django.db import models
import datetime

## Create your models here.

class recipe(models.Model):

```
Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Directions = models.TextField()
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return (self.id, self.Name)
```

class ingredients(models.Model):

```
Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
Units = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Recipe = models.ForeignKey(recipe)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Name
```

class meals(models.Model):

```
Breakfast = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Lunch = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Dinner = models.CharField(max_length=200)
servingDate = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Comment: What errors were you getting?

Comment: I am getting error 200

Comment: In that case I'm not getting an error. Which is weird, when I check the rendered page source, the form is there but just the start and ends tags, no content. Figured I was just misusing the ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Paste your `models.py`, because you have some basic issues but I want to make sure there isn't anything wrong with your models :)

Comment: Added the models to my original post. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

did you import the `mealForm`:

some thing like :`from app.forms import mealForm`

form is a function. so try:

```
args['form'] = mealForm()
```

Note: don't use `render_to_response`. it is old use `render` instead(so don't even need csrf)::

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def...(request):
....
return render(request,'newMeal.html', {'form': mealForm()})
```

Comment: thanks for the pro-tip re render_to_response. I double checked and I am importing the form and I get the same thing, pages renders but with no content. If I remove the ModelChoiceField from the form everything renders just dandy. I added the whole form.py code to my original post, I'm sure it's some weird rookie mistake I'm making.